# What is the best way to handle my own old unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

I asked an (upvoted) question a year ago but never received any answer.

At this moment it also isn't that important to me since I solved it in a completely different way.

Should I remove the question to have my acceptance rate at 100% again?
Or just leave it unanswered?

Comment: I take it the "completely different way" wouldn't be an answer to the question as asked then?

Comment: If there is no answer at all to the question, it doesn't count for the accept rate anyway.

Comment: @Roeland: your visible acceptance rate *is* at 100%.

Comment: Yes, now it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you solved it, you can post an answer yourself. If not you can leave it for other users. Someone else might find a solution to it and post it. And in the future it might be useful to others.

Accept rate does not mean a thing. Don't remove questions for the sake of it!

Comment: No, but people my not respond if it is low. But I think you are correct in not deleting a question for this reason.